# Selecting multiple columns and rows for formatting - Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2003

I have a report which I used the command subtotals. Aesthetically, I just want to make these subtotal rows (columns A to P) filled with color, be in Bold and have a surrounding border. There are hundreds of totals generated in my report. And they do not have a recurring row position. So basically in order for it to look good, I do it manually per row. Is there a faster way? Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to generate the reports?

Answer (score 0):

Use either Range.Interior, or Range.FormatConditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on continuing to do it manually, you should set up one cell or row exactly how you want it. Bold, color and border and then double click on the paint brush icon on your standard toolbar; then just highlight your next row or cell and the formatting will appear. Once you are finished formatting, click back on the paint brush to stop the formatting. This a great time saver and makes all totals aesthetically identical.